# Show hidden files from windows PC on Mac

Tags: mac, windows, macos

I created some hidden files in windows and copied them on pen drive. Now i want to see those files in Mac but not able to see. please tell how i can see those files ?
thanks

Comment: How did you format the pen drive? What do you see when you plug the pen drive into the Mac?

Comment: Pen drive was formatted on windows (quick format). when i plug pen drive into mac, i see no hidden files.

Comment: How are the files hidden (sorry I have forgotten some Windows things)

Comment: right click the folder and then select HIDE. i hide the folder which contained my files

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=894225) post seems like the most likely answer to your question. In Terminal, `cd` to your drive where `ls` should list all files, including your hidden ones. To 'unhide' a file in Finder, type

```
chflags nohidden [folder name]
```

Where [folder name] is obviously the name of your hidden folder.

Note I've confirmed this working on my Mac running OSX.10 Yosemite and an NTFS formatted drive from Windows XP x64 professional.